# Can't access the user profiles in a console application

Tags: development, user-profile

I want to make some manipulation with the user profiles from a console application.

I'm trying to enumerate the profiles, with no success :

```
        var mysite = "http://my";

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>{
            var site = new SPSite(mysite);
            var ctx = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            var upm = new UserProfileManager(ctx);

            foreach (UserProfile profile in upm)
            {
                var login = profile["AccountName"].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(login);
            }

        });
```

This code throw an exception at the creation of the UserProfileManager instance :

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.CheckAdministrationAccess(UserProfileApplicationAdminRights rights, Boolean requireAllRights)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.CheckAdministrationAccess(UserProfileApplicationAdminRights rights)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.CanManagePeople(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.get_IsProfileAdmin()
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext)
       at MyApp.Program.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Main>b__3() in C:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\Program.cs:line 25
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
  InnerException:
```

What can be the cause of the error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, this is a permission issue. If you are administrator, make sure the conole app runs as administrator. Check link below:

http://sureshannamalai.blogspot.com/2011/08/get-user-profile-using-console-app.html

Comment: Actually, the error come because my user, even if he is farm administrator, was not explicitly granted full control on the service. Thanks for putting me on the right way. Non-thanks to Microsoft for such awful error message

Comment: hell yeah u right, about error message.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the userprofile object is returning null. This can happen due to permission rights for the user, even though it is running with SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges().

Can you try out the solution provided in this post? - http://socialsp.com/2010/11/25/access-denied-messages-when-retrieving-sharepoint-user-profiles-count-even-running-in-elevated-code/

Finally, your code would look like this -

```
var mysite = "http://my";
HttpContext tempCtx = HttpContext.Current;
        try
       {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>{
            var site = new SPSite(mysite);
            var ctx = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            HttpContext.Current = null;
            var upm = new UserProfileManager(ctx);
            foreach (UserProfile profile in upm)
            {
                var login = profile["AccountName"].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(login);
            }
        });
        }
        catch (Exception ex){ LogException(ex);}
        finally{ HttpContext.Current = tempCtx;}
```

Comment: I work with a **console application**. This workaround does not apply as HttpContext is already null.

Comment: I guess I missed that. It should be permission issues. Make sure the app is running under Admin privileges. Did you try the User Profile Service in Central Admin? Click Permisions in the ribbon and add the user with Full Control permissions.

Comment: it is the solution, as Ashish Patel mentionned in its answer. thx for the help anyway